# Spring Boot `TestPropertySource` not Working

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

I have a simple unit test, and I'd like for the unit tests to load up a test property file that I've placed in `src/test/resources/test.properties` instead of the property file in `src/main/resources/application.properties`.

My test class is set up as follows:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:src/test/resources/properties-test.yml")
public class SecurityConfigurationTest {
    @MockBean
    KafkaConfiguration kafkaConfiguration;

    @MockBean
    KafkaMonitor kafkaMonitor;

    @MockBean
    BuildProperties buildProperties;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void unauthorizedUser_shouldNotAccessHomePage() throws Exception{
        mockMvc
                .perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

}
```

My project file structure is as shown below:
[image]

But I am getting the following error, suggesting I'm not specifying this property file correctly:

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/test/resources/test.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

How do can I manage to get the `test.properties` file to be used instead of the `application.properties` file for my unit tests?

Answer (score 1):

In pom.xml add a **profiles tag** which specifies which properties file should the program choose when it runs.

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>test</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Note: name of your properties file must be **application-test.properties**.

This will make your test properties active but to access it you need to configure your test resource folder and let the intellij know 'use this when running.

In Intellij, you can change your resource folder with which you run your project, so you need to....

1. Select test resource folder.
2. Right click on it. In the opened menu, select **Modify Run Configuration** and create a new configuration.

This means a new **Run Configuration** is created for running test resource folder.

3. Run the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Maven by default will package all files in the `src/test/resources/` folder to the classpath. So to refer it by the classpath , it should be :

```java
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
```

Alternatively, if you want to refer it by the system file path , you can change it to :

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "file:src/test/resources/test.properties")
```

Under the cover , its uses `ResourceLoader` to load the file. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#resources-resourceloader) for more details.